# Why can't my variable be resolved?

Tags: java

I'm getting an error in eclipse after new Machine and New Camera saying variable cannot be resolved.I tried changing the compiler to 1.7 and i'm still getting this error.

```
class Machine {
    public void start(){    
        System.out.println("Machine Started");
    }
}

class Camera extends Machine {
    public void start(){         
        System.out.println("Camera Started");
    }
    public void snap(){
        System.out.println("Photo taken");
    }
}

public class UpdownCasting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Machine machine1 = new Machine;
        Camera camera1 = new Camera; 
    }

}
```

Comment: because you´re missing the paranthesis as `new Machine();`

Comment: you are just invoking wrongly the constructor of those classes

Comment: Thanks guys, it was so simple i couldn't see it. I knew it was something extremely small and stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write the paranthesis:

```
   Machine machine1 = new Machine();
   Camera camera1 = new Camera();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call constructor. `()` after the class means you want to call a default no-arg constructor.

```
class Machine {
    public void start(){    
        System.out.println("Machine Started");
    }
}

class Camera extends Machine {
    public void start(){         
        System.out.println("Camera Started");
    }
    public void snap(){
        System.out.println("Photo taken");
    }
}

public class UpdownCasting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Machine machine1 = new Machine();
        Camera camera1 = new Camera(); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `write()` after the class name variable.